# PostgreSQL receives bytea instead of null from Spring repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I am trying to call a stored procedure from my java spring server using a native query like this:

```
@Query(value =
  "SELECT * FROM my_function(?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5, ?6 ,?7, ?8, ?9, ?10 , ?11, ?12, ?13, ?14)",
  nativeQuery = true)
  List<Object> findByFilters(*14 input parameters here*);
```

I later fill this list of objects in my service, and pass it to the  controller class which I call by comoposing a URL with optional parameters. 
Now, when all the parameters have actual values everything works fine and the results i'm expecting are correctly returned.
However when some of the parameters is null ( or all of them are ) i get :

```
    [2013/09/25 14:01:44] [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] [WARN ] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
[2013/09/25 14:01:44] [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] [ERROR] ERROR: function car_filters(bytea, bytea, bytea, bytea, bytea, bytea, bytea, bytea, bytea, bytea, bytea, bytea, bytea, bytea) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Any idea why Hibernate sends bytearrays instead of nulls to my Postgre server?

Comment: Can you share the exact method (java) and function (postgres) definition? Are you overloading the function?